# How to map key values in sub sub objects from an array in java script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2

**I was trying to access key, values from the below array**

> **I am trying to access keys inside the fields object and value from the model inside keys object**

```
formFields = [
        {
            "title": "Criteria Details",
            "columns": 2,
            "fields": {
                "criteriaName": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "Criteria Name",
                    "id": 'criteriaName',
                    "model": "CRITERIA 1",
                    "required": true,
                    "show": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Criteria Name is required',
                    ]
                },
                "criteriaType": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Criteria type",
                    "id": "criteriaType",
                    "options": ['Dependent', 'Independent', 'Static'],
                    "model": "Dependent",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Criteria Type is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                },
                "table": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Table",
                    "id": "table",
                    "options": ["Table1"],
                    "model": "Table1",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Table is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                },
                "column": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Column",
                    "id": "column",
                    "options": ["Column1"],
                    "model": "Column1",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Column is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                },
                "joinType": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Join Type",
                    "id": "joinType",
                    "options": ["AND", "OR"],
                    "model": "OR",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Join Type is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                },
                "operator": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Operator",
                    "id": "operator",
                    "options": ["<", "<=", "<>", "=", ">=", ">", "EXISTS", "IN", "IS NOT NULL", "NULL", "LIKE", "NOT EXISTS", "NOT IN", "NOT LIKE"],
                    "model": ">=",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Operator is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                },
                "valueType": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Value Type",
                    "id": "valueType",
                    "options": ["Dependent SQL", "SQL", "VALUE"],
                    "model": "SQL",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Value Type is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                },
                "dataType": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Data Type",
                    "id": "dataType",
                    "options": ["DATE", "NUMBER", "STRING"],
                    "model": "NUMBER",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Data Type is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                },
                "format": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "label": "Format",
                    "id": "format",
                    "model": "Config",
                    "required": false,
                    "show": true,
                },
                "parameterMandatory": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Parameter Mandatory",
                    "id": "parameterMandatory",
                    "options": ["NO", "YES"],
                    "model": "YES",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Parameter Mandatory is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                },
                "link": {
                    "type": "select",
                    "label": "Link",
                    "id": "link",
                    "options": ["KB"],
                    "model": "KB",
                    "required": false,
                    "show": true,
                },
                "sequence": {
                    'type': "text",
                    "label": "Sequence",
                    "id": "sequence",
                    "model": "SEQ1",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Sequence is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                },
                "value": {
                    "type": "description_notes",
                    "label": "Value",
                    "id": "value",
                    "model": "VAL",
                    "required": true,
                    "rules": [
                        v => !!v || 'Value is required',
                    ],
                    "show": true,
                }
            }
        },
        {
            'title': "Notes",
            "columns": 1,
            "fields": {
                "description": {
                    "type": "description_notes",
                    "label": "Description",
                    "id": "description",
                    "required": false,
                    "model": 'abcde',
                    "show": true,
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

> ****The Output i was trying is like this.****
>   **How to access the keys and values from the above array like this.
>   Which method we need to use**

```
criteriaDetails: [
    {"criteriaName": "CRITERIA 1"}, 
    {"criteriaType": "Dependent"},
    {"table": "Table1"},
    {"column": "Column1"},
    {"joinType": "OR"},
    {"operator": ">="},
    {"valueType": "SQL"},
    {"dataType": "NUMBER"},
    {"format": "Config"},
    {"parameterMandatory": "YES"},
    {"link": "KB"},
    {"sequence": "SEQ1"},
    {"value": "VAL"},
    {"description": "abcde"}
]
```

**I tried below code**

```
const field = this.formFields.map(field => {
      return Object.entries(field.fields)
})
console.log(field)
```

> how can I achieve this?
>   How to solve this. Please help

```
Thanks..
```

Comment: Do you only want the `criteriaDetails`? Or do you want to repeat this for every item in your array?

Comment: every item. forget criteriaDetails.

Comment: In your example your output shows an array that has `criteriaName`, `criteriaType` in a specific order (same as the input object from top to bottom). If that order is critical then you can't use any of the given answers because Object.entries, Object.keys, `for ... in/of` to get key/values of an object does not guarantee any order. In fact it states you'll get them [in an arbitrary order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Deleted_added_or_modified_properties)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like all you need to do is iterate over each `fields` object, and extract the key and the `model` property from each:

```js
const formFields=[{"title":"Criteria Details","columns":2,"fields":{"criteriaName":{"type":"text","label":"Criteria Name","id":'criteriaName',"model":"CRITERIA 1","required":!0,"show":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Criteria Name is required',]},"criteriaType":{"type":"select","label":"Criteria type","id":"criteriaType","options":['Dependent','Independent','Static'],"model":"Dependent","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Criteria Type is required',],"show":!0,},"table":{"type":"select","label":"Table","id":"table","options":["Table1"],"model":"Table1","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Table is required',],"show":!0,},"column":{"type":"select","label":"Column","id":"column","options":["Column1"],"model":"Column1","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Column is required',],"show":!0,},"joinType":{"type":"select","label":"Join Type","id":"joinType","options":["AND","OR"],"model":"OR","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Join Type is required',],"show":!0,},"operator":{"type":"select","label":"Operator","id":"operator","options":["<","<=","<>","=",">=",">","EXISTS","IN","IS NOT NULL","NULL","LIKE","NOT EXISTS","NOT IN","NOT LIKE"],"model":">=","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Operator is required',],"show":!0,},"valueType":{"type":"select","label":"Value Type","id":"valueType","options":["Dependent SQL","SQL","VALUE"],"model":"SQL","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Value Type is required',],"show":!0,},"dataType":{"type":"select","label":"Data Type","id":"dataType","options":["DATE","NUMBER","STRING"],"model":"NUMBER","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Data Type is required',],"show":!0,},"format":{"type":"text","label":"Format","id":"format","model":"Config","required":!1,"show":!0,},"parameterMandatory":{"type":"select","label":"Parameter Mandatory","id":"parameterMandatory","options":["NO","YES"],"model":"YES","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Parameter Mandatory is required',],"show":!0,},"link":{"type":"select","label":"Link","id":"link","options":["KB"],"model":"KB","required":!1,"show":!0,},"sequence":{'type':"text","label":"Sequence","id":"sequence","model":"SEQ1","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Sequence is required',],"show":!0,},"value":{"type":"description_notes","label":"Value","id":"value","model":"VAL","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Value is required',],"show":!0,}}},{'title':"Notes","columns":1,"fields":{"description":{"type":"description_notes","label":"Description","id":"description","required":!1,"model":'abcde',"show":!0,}}}]
    
const output = [];
formFields.forEach(({ fields }) => {
  Object.entries(fields).forEach(([key, { model }]) => {
    output.push({ [key]: model });
  });
});
console.log(output);
```

The `({ fields})` is destructuring the object you pass to the callback. It would be equivalent to

```
formFields.forEach((obj) => {
    Object.entries(obj.fields)
```

`Object.entries` will return an array with two values, the first is the current key and the second is the object associated with the key. That's why you can destructure again with `(([key, { model }])`.

As a reference you could rewrite the whole thing as

```
formFields.forEach((curObj) => {
  Object.entries(curObj.fields).forEach(([key, fieldValues]) => {
    output[key] = fieldValues.model;
  });
});
```

Comment: Using an object as input data type is not a good idea if the output is expected to be in a certain order because any of the object key/values itterator does not guarantee the [order in which you'll get them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) in fact it says in arbitrary order. Code will happen to work on JSON data but this is not guaranteed and can break.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const formFields = [{"title":"Criteria Details","columns":2,"fields":{"criteriaName":{"type":"text","label":"Criteria Name","id":'criteriaName',"model":"CRITERIA 1","required":!0,"show":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Criteria Name is required',]},"criteriaType":{"type":"select","label":"Criteria type","id":"criteriaType","options":['Dependent','Independent','Static'],"model":"Dependent","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Criteria Type is required',],"show":!0,},"table":{"type":"select","label":"Table","id":"table","options":["Table1"],"model":"Table1","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Table is required',],"show":!0,},"column":{"type":"select","label":"Column","id":"column","options":["Column1"],"model":"Column1","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Column is required',],"show":!0,},"joinType":{"type":"select","label":"Join Type","id":"joinType","options":["AND","OR"],"model":"OR","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Join Type is required',],"show":!0,},"operator":{"type":"select","label":"Operator","id":"operator","options":["<","<=","<>","=",">=",">","EXISTS","IN","IS NOT NULL","NULL","LIKE","NOT EXISTS","NOT IN","NOT LIKE"],"model":">=","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Operator is required',],"show":!0,},"valueType":{"type":"select","label":"Value Type","id":"valueType","options":["Dependent SQL","SQL","VALUE"],"model":"SQL","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Value Type is required',],"show":!0,},"dataType":{"type":"select","label":"Data Type","id":"dataType","options":["DATE","NUMBER","STRING"],"model":"NUMBER","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Data Type is required',],"show":!0,},"format":{"type":"text","label":"Format","id":"format","model":"Config","required":!1,"show":!0,},"parameterMandatory":{"type":"select","label":"Parameter Mandatory","id":"parameterMandatory","options":["NO","YES"],"model":"YES","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Parameter Mandatory is required',],"show":!0,},"link":{"type":"select","label":"Link","id":"link","options":["KB"],"model":"KB","required":!1,"show":!0,},"sequence":{'type':"text","label":"Sequence","id":"sequence","model":"SEQ1","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Sequence is required',],"show":!0,},"value":{"type":"description_notes","label":"Value","id":"value","model":"VAL","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Value is required',],"show":!0,}}},{'title':"Notes","columns":1,"fields":{"description":{"type":"description_notes","label":"Description","id":"description","required":!1,"model":'abcde',"show":!0,}}}]
let result = []
formFields.forEach(item => {
    const entries = Object.entries(item.fields)
    entries.forEach(([key, { model }]) => {
        result.push({
            [key]: model
        })
    })
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

You can use the `Array.prototype.reduce()` method to reduce the array to a single value, and use the `Object.entries` static method to extract the key and value

```
const formFields=[{"title":"Criteria Details","columns":2,"fields":{"criteriaName":{"type":"text","label":"Criteria Name","id":'criteriaName',"model":"CRITERIA 1","required":!0,"show":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Criteria Name is required',]},"criteriaType":{"type":"select","label":"Criteria type","id":"criteriaType","options":['Dependent','Independent','Static'],"model":"Dependent","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Criteria Type is required',],"show":!0,},"table":{"type":"select","label":"Table","id":"table","options":["Table1"],"model":"Table1","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Table is required',],"show":!0,},"column":{"type":"select","label":"Column","id":"column","options":["Column1"],"model":"Column1","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Column is required',],"show":!0,},"joinType":{"type":"select","label":"Join Type","id":"joinType","options":["AND","OR"],"model":"OR","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Join Type is required',],"show":!0,},"operator":{"type":"select","label":"Operator","id":"operator","options":["<","<=","<>","=",">=",">","EXISTS","IN","IS NOT NULL","NULL","LIKE","NOT EXISTS","NOT IN","NOT LIKE"],"model":">=","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Operator is required',],"show":!0,},"valueType":{"type":"select","label":"Value Type","id":"valueType","options":["Dependent SQL","SQL","VALUE"],"model":"SQL","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Value Type is required',],"show":!0,},"dataType":{"type":"select","label":"Data Type","id":"dataType","options":["DATE","NUMBER","STRING"],"model":"NUMBER","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Data Type is required',],"show":!0,},"format":{"type":"text","label":"Format","id":"format","model":"Config","required":!1,"show":!0,},"parameterMandatory":{"type":"select","label":"Parameter Mandatory","id":"parameterMandatory","options":["NO","YES"],"model":"YES","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Parameter Mandatory is required',],"show":!0,},"link":{"type":"select","label":"Link","id":"link","options":["KB"],"model":"KB","required":!1,"show":!0,},"sequence":{'type':"text","label":"Sequence","id":"sequence","model":"SEQ1","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Sequence is required',],"show":!0,},"value":{"type":"description_notes","label":"Value","id":"value","model":"VAL","required":!0,"rules":[v=>!!v||'Value is required',],"show":!0,}}},{'title':"Notes","columns":1,"fields":{"description":{"type":"description_notes","label":"Description","id":"description","required":!1,"model":'abcde',"show":!0,}}}]

const output = formFields.reduce((accumulator, { fields }) => {
  return Object.assign(accumulator, Object.entries(fields)
    .reduce((accumulatorInside, [key, { model }]) => {
      accumulatorInside[key] = model;
      return accumulatorInside;
    }, {})
  )
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Or you can use loops

```
const output = {};

for (let index = 0; index < formFields.length; index++) {
  for (let key in formFields[index].fields) {
    if (formFields[index].fields.hasOwnProperty(key))
      output[key] = formFields[index].fields[key].model;
  }
}

console.log(output);
```

You could also do this with `Array.prototype.forEach()`(from @certainperformance answer, go up-vote that too)

```
const output = {};

formFields.forEach(({ fields }) => {
  Object.entries(fields).forEach(([key, { model }]) => {
    output[key] = model;
  });
});

console.log(output);
```

The basic idea is the same regardless. You need to iterate over the properties and set the values.

From a performance standpoint: closures that move outside their scope are slower than functions that do not, and `for...in` loops are the fastest, but the most verbose to use.

BE CAREFUL! `for...in` loops do have some caveats! The reason I do the check for the own property is to prevent copying any prototypes. This is the one issue with the loop. You may instead want to use a `for` loop with the array returned with `Object.getOWnPropertyNames()` static method instead since it is safer and won't traverse prototypes, but it adds extra time complexity.

These are however considerations when you don't want to use side effects(`Array.prototype.forEach()`) or need to squeeze as MUCH speed as possible out of your code.